# updated integer value in edittext is not retrieving

Tags: android

I have two components in my activity i.e an edittext of input type numeric and a button.
in onCreate function of my activity,i put

```
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   editText.setText("1");
```

But user has the option to change it.
onClick of the button,i am showing this numeric value in a textview.
here is my onClick function

```
public void onClick(View view){
    int i=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    textView.setText(i+"");
}
```

but every time it picks the default value i.e 1,not the changed value if some one changes it before clicking on button.
here is full code

```
public class Edittext1 extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edittext1);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        editText.setText("1");
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        textView.setText(i + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not adding anything? try i+1 ;-)

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: As I can see you have an EditText, a TextView and a Button, but you said you only had an EditText and a Button. Could you please tell us correctly what are you looking for?

Comment: actually i+"" is just to convert integer into string so that textview can show it.i am not adding anything here.

Comment: ya i have a textview too.sorry...

Comment: you probably have a problem with how you reference the EditText. Please post more code

Comment: is that your onclick() function working? have you debugged

Comment: yess,whats wrong in it.?

Comment: set onclicklistner for button

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.getText().toString());
```

You are missing the parenthesis for the `getText()`.

Comment: no,here i typed it so i missed it but i didnt missed it in my code.

Comment: then its definitely because you haven't set the setOnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

You missed to set `setOnClickListener` to button

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

OR

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DoIt(v);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the `onClick` method. I guess you have created the `OnClickListener` inside the button's XML, right?

Sometimes, I had problems with that. So try this:

First declare a global `Button` variable.

`Button button;`

Then, inside `onCreate`:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //Put the content of the onClick method in here
            //And remove the onClick method
    }
});
```